# Parallel.Foreach, Adding child node to a parent

Tags: .net, vb.net, parallel-processing, treenode, parallel.foreach

UPDATE:

Changed my code around and moved adding the nodes to the treeview out of the Parallel loop, but I'm running into an ArgumentException error.

At `SetNode.Nodes.Add(CardNode)` I'm getting `Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.`

```
Parallel.ForEach(CardSetIDs, Sub(CardSetIDArray)
    CardName = CardSetIDArray(0)
    SetName = CardSetIDArray(1)
    CardID = CardSetIDArray(2)
    SetNode = SetNodesDict(SetName)
    CardNode = New TreeNode(CardName)
    CardNode.Tag = CardName & " - " & SetName
    AllCardsDict.TryAdd(CardName & " - " & SetName, CardID)
    SetNode.Nodes.Add(CardNode)
    bgwBTV.ReportProgress(CardProgress)
    CardsDone += 1
    CardProgress = PercentDone(CardsDone, CardSetIDs.Count)
End Sub)
```

---

I'm trying to build a TreeView in the background via BackgroundWorker. Within the BackgroundWorker.DoWork, I want to try to add my children to their proper parents in parallel since there's ~25k of them, but I'm running into a strange (at least to me) situation where an ArgumentException is thrown because the key already exists, even though there are no duplicates in the array that's holding the data for my nodes.

```
Parallel.ForEach(ParentChildIDs, Sub(ParentChildIDArray)
    ChildName = ParentChildIDArray(0)
    ParentName = ParentChildIDArray(1)
    ChildID = ParentChildIDArray(2)
    ParentNode = trvParents.Nodes(ParentName)
    ChildNode = New TreeNode(ChildName)
    ChildNode.Tag = ChildName & " - " & ParentName
    AllChildrenDict.Add(ChildName & " - " & ParentName, ChildID)
    ParentNode.Nodes.Add(ChildNode)
    bgw.ReportProgress(ChildProgress)
    ChildrenDone += 1
    ChildProgress = PercentDone(ChildDone, ParentChildIDs.Count)
End Sub)
```

Bolded lines are where I'm running into the ArgumentException.

Comment: Just found out about the ConcurrentDictionary object, so, that answers my question for AllChildrenDict, but, I'm still in search for a solution for my TreeNodes.

Comment: What about the TreeNodes?

Comment: You get errors because multiple threads try to change the same node collection. A `ConcurrentDictionary` only synchronises the access to the dictionary itself. You need to synchronise the access to the node collections also.

Answer (score 0):

You should not do that in parallel. The tree node is not thread-safe, I guess it should be accessed only in the same thread that has created it (which should be the UI thread).

In case you have many nodes, you may consider lazy loading only the visible nodes, this take more code and becomes more complex, but can make your UI much more responsive.